# [nodejs][meteor] s3zip returns a file ending with `*.dms` instead of `*.zip`

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, meteor, zip

I am compressing a few images from our S3 bucket using `s3-zip`, but the zip is returned as a file with the ending `*.dms`. When I rename the file as `*.zip` it does un-compress fine.

the only hits on google I can find regarding DMS are database migration...

here is the code:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/download', (req, res, next) => {

const opts = {
    Bucket: Meteor.settings.s3.bucket,
    region: Meteor.settings.s3.region,
    // Key: thing.assets[assetKey].path
};

// doing some stuff to get an array of images with paths ...
const poolImages = [];
const directory = 'path/to/images';
// done... lets make a zip


const archive = s3Zip
    .setFormat('zip')
    .archive({ s3: s3Client, region: opts.region, bucket: opts.Bucket, debug: true }, directory, poolImages)
// .pipe(res)
// .res(end);

archive.on('error', (e) => {
    res.writeHead(500).end(e.message);
});

// archive.on('end', () => {
//     console.log('archive created');
// });

archive.pipe(res).on('response', function(res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/zip'
         });
     });
});
```

with debug enabled it seems to work as intended.

```
I20220727-23:37:59.185(1)? append to zip d904450a3cd211c9cdccb4999d5c8f6e.jpg
I20220727-23:37:59.198(1)? append to zip 94f7bc35c45ca6ee3976d00f5aa1aa28.jpg
I20220727-23:37:59.205(1)? append to zip b3e6027e1ca57e4e800438106ff8ae30.jpg
I20220727-23:37:59.206(1)? end -> finalize
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt set the headers right... classic.

```
const name = 'download.zip';
const disposition = `filename=\"${encodeURI(name).replace(/\,/g, '%2C')}\"; filename*=UTF-8''${encodeURIComponent(name)}; `;
const dispositionEncoding = 'charset=UTF-8';

res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; ${disposition}${dispositionEncoding}`);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
```